# Stm32f303 freertos

Tags: gcc, stm32, freertos

I try to run freertos on stm32f303 discovery.
I include all header and source files from freertos archive downloaded from official web site. Also I include portable files from folder `/GCC/ARM_CM4F`. 
I use codesourcery lite compiler. And when I try to compile project i get error:

```
In file included from freertos/inc/portable.h:321:0,
                 from freertos/inc/FreeRTOS.h:100,
                 from freertos/src/croutine.c:66:
freertos/inc/portmacro.h:167:7: error: missing binary operator before token "long"
```

`portmacro.h`'s 167-172 strings:

```
    #if( configMAX_PRIORITIES > 32 )
        #error configUSE_PORT_OPTIMISED_TASK_SELECTION can only be set to 1 when configMAX_PRIORITIES is less than or equal to 32.  It is very rare that a system requires more than 10 to 15 difference priorities as tasks that share a priority will time slice.
    #endif
```

Searching in Google give that there is preprocessor error but it don't get me point what I should to do.
My Makefile settings:

```
# Set Libraries
LIBS        = -lm -lc

###################################################
# Set Board
MCU         = -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4
FPU         = -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp
DEFINES     = -DSTM32F3XX -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER
DEFINES     += -DUSE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_CALLBACK

# Set Compilation and Linking Flags
CFLAGS      = $(MCU) $(FPU) $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES) \
            -g -Wall -std=gnu90 -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
ASFLAGS     = $(MCU) $(FPU) -g -Wa,--warn -x assembler-with-cpp
LDFLAGS     = $(MCU) $(FPU) -g -gdwarf-2\
            -Tstm32f30_flash.ld \
            -Xlinker --gc-sections -Wl,-Map=$(PROJ_NAME).map \
            $(LIBS) \
            -o $(PROJ_NAME).elf
```

Where I am mistaken?

Answer (score 5):

The compiler is telling you the C pre-processor does not understand the definition of configMAX_PRIORITIES.  Look at the definition in FreeRTOSConfig.h, I suspect it includes a cast that the pre-processor does not understand.  Remove the cast and it will probably be ok.

Comment: See also the discussion on the FreeRTOS support forums. [link](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/October_2014/freertos_FreeRTOS_V812_portmacro.h_missing_binary_operator_before_token_long_bffa0f71j.html)